# Validating passed arguments with contracts?

Tags: c#, code-contracts, system.diagnostics

Usually, when I want to check if, let's say a constructor argument is initialized, I do it like this:

```
public MyCtor(MyObj obj) {
    if(obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
}
```

However recently I stumpled upon this nice feature from the *System.Diagnostics* namespace:

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(condition);
```

Does this have the same effect? Are there any drawbacks when using *Contracts* to validate arguments?

Comment: Contracts allows you to use the static code contract analysis tool, which allows you find issues before you when run the coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes unless:

> You must turn on run-time checking to use the Requires method.

(from MSDN). Instruction how to turn it on must be somewhere [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970).

An alternative is `CuttingEdge.Conditions`:

```
Condition.Requires(obj).IsNotNull();
Condition.Requires(myIntValue).IsGreaterThan(0);
Condition.Requries(myString).IsNotNullOrWhitespace();
```

More on [codeplex](http://conditions.codeplex.com).

This do the same job but syntax simpler and more `human` readable (in my opinion) - so there has no drawbacks (but remeber: it's opinion based). Is use it since I've discovered :)

Comment: CuttingEdge.Conditions really does look nice! But where do I declare the exception that gets thrown?

Comment: @xvdiff It's automatically detected :) (`IsNotNull` throws `ArgumentNullException`, `IsGreaterThan` throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`). For custom exceptions: `Condition.WithExceptionOnFailure<MyExceeption>().Requires(collection).DoesNotContain(item);`